# Drag and drop for fill in the blanks using JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Below is my scenario explanation in screenshot,

[image]

From the above mentioned picture.Brown box positions are defined as droppable and the below choices are draggable.If I drag drop it is working fine.

[image]

If I drag another option in already defined place its overlapping for example

[image]

What I want to do is it will replace text as "venerated" and already dropped text "supercious" will come back to the text of choices in below box.How can I do this .Please anyone help me to get out of this issue.
Below is my code

```
  <!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style> 
.box1
{
background: #E7AC9F;
height: 20px;
width: 100px;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.di1{
    border: 1px dotted #22BAA0;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: move;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style> 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script> 
$( function() {
$(".box1").sortable();
    $(".box1").disableSelection();

    $(".qitem2").draggable({
        containment : "#container",
        helper : 'clone',
        revert : 'invalid'
    });

    $(".box1, #qlist2").droppable({
        hoverClass : 'ui-state-highlight',
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop : function(ev, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
            $(ui.draggable).removeAttr("style");

        }
    });
    });
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<p>The multi-coloured eyes,<div class="box1"></div>and striking facial cuts and curves<div class="box1"></div>  the Siberian Husky as one of the most desirable and breeds <div class="box1"></div>of dogs. Originally from Siberia, they look like replicas of wolves; also, they are challenging to new owners due to their agility and<div class="box1"></div></p>

<div id="qlist2">
    <div class="qitem2 di1">
        Option 1
    </div>
    <div class="qitem2 di1">
       Option 2
    </div>
    <div class="qitem2 di1">
        Option 3
    </div>
    <div class="qitem2 di1">
        Option 4
    </div>
     <div class="qitem2 di1">
        Option 5
    </div>
     <div class="qitem2 di1">
        Option 6
    </div>
     <div class="qitem2 di1">
        Option 6
    </div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What I understand from your question is... you want to drop a single drag element in the drop slot.... if there is already one draggable is present in dropslot, then the another drag element should not be allowed to be dropped in that drop slot...... do you want this?

Comment: U got almost.If I try to drop in already dropped place it will drop and already present drop will be move to below choice list.Read again You will understand

Comment: @KavyaShree I think few days ago you got the solution, what happen now?

Comment: That is different scenario @aavrug.

Comment: Show us the working example that will be more helpful.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/KavyaBabu/b9pLet17/ check this..

Comment: This jsfiddle is blank :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132087/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-aavrug).

Comment: Check the above code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make an container for draggables elements so that whenever second element is dropped in droppable we can move first element in it's container

HTML :

```
 <div id="qlist2">
  <div id = "dragitem1-container" class="drag-container">
  <div id="dragitem1" class="qitem2 di1">
    Option 1
  </div>
</div>

<div id = "dragitem2-container" class="drag-container">
  <div id="dragitem2" class="qitem2 di1">
    Option 2
  </div>
</div>

<div id = "dragitem3-container" class="drag-container">
   <div id="dragitem3" class="qitem2 di1">
       Option 3
   </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="droppable-element">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function makedraggable() {
 $(".qitem2").draggable({
        "revert": "invalid"
 });
```

}

makedraggable();

```
 $(".droppable-element").droppable({
    "accept": ".qitem2",
    "drop": function(event, ui) {
        if ($(this).find(".qitem2").length) {
            var $presentChild = $(this).find(".qitem2"),
                currChildId = $presentChild.attr("id"),
                $currChildContainer = $("#" + currChildId + "-container");                  
           $currChildContainer.append($presentChild);
           $presentChild.removeAttr("style");
           makedraggable();
        }

        $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this).removeAttr("style");
        $(ui.draggable).remove();

    }
 })
})
```

I think this is what you want

https://jsfiddle.net/4bL4tfrt/

Comment: The best way to do this..... make container of draggables as droppable.... so whenever user drop draggable elements in the container enable the droppable.... If this is not the required answer show us fiddle in which we can try

Comment: If I do in this way it wont allow other option to drop .I dnt want to do like this It will replace new drop and old draggable text will be again move to option.as below mentioned options

Comment: Read my question again @kenny

Comment: @KavyaShree please check fiddle... is this is what you want?

Comment: its perfectly right. Can u tell me how to remove style after drop and set that text at center of box

Comment: The best way to do that is to add and remove classes..... define a class in your css file.... give it css you want... and add/remove that class where you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132095/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-kenny).